# How to add key NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription to info.plist in a Windows Visual Studio xamarin.ios app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, info.plist

I need to add BLUETOOTH LOW ENERGY (ble) to my xamarin.ios app, which I build on windows Visual Studio paired to my Macbook.  BLE on xamarin.ios requires NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription in info.plist.

However, I can't figure out how to do it with the info.plist GUI in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To add it, I opened info.plist with Notepad (or any text editor) and inserted the lines...
NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription
To test our device for BLE
...near the end.

Example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>BluetoothTest</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>pl.wojciechkulik.BluetoothTest</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.3</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <!--for connecting to devices (client)-->
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>

        <!--for server configurations if needed-->
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    </array>

    <!--Description of the Bluetooth request message (required on iOS 10, deprecated)-->
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>

    <!--Description of the Bluetooth request message (required on iOS 13)-->
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string></dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, I can't figure out how to do it with the info.plist GUI in Visual Studio.

There are two ways to add `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription` for `info.plist` in Visual Studio.

**One** is open with **XML(Text)Editor**

[image]

[image]

Then add it bellow `<dict></dict>` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription </string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Another way** is open with **Generic Plist Editor** :

[image]

Then can click **+** button to select **Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description** and type Value .

[image]

More info can refer to [Setting Privacy Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/security-privacy?tabs=windows#accessing-private-user-data).